# WordPress - Media library shows 503 error in console

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-503

My media library is not working correctly when I want to upload a image i get a `HTTP Error` sometimes, not every time. When I look in my browser console I see multiple 503 errors and 404 errors. I dont know where they are coming from.

I tried, upping my memory limit and disabling all plugins.

Here is a screenshot of the errors in the console:

[image: Console errors]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot WordPress errors, you require to enable WordPress Debug, which can be done using **wp-config.php**.
You need to copy and paste the code in **wp-config.php** file shown below.
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

[How To Debug And Log Errors In WordPress Site](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-debug-and-log-errors-in-wordpress-site/)

Also,  contact your web host.